# Next 13 - Attach JWT on every API call with custom server using axios

Tags: authentication, next.js, axios, jwt, authorization

I am currently working on a Next.js 13 app that uses JWT approach for authentication.
I already have an existing Express server with all the routes I need and I have to stick to this server until I move it to Next.js also.

What I am trying to do is whenever I make a request on a Server Component using axios, attach the Bearer token saved inside of cookies.

```
api.ts

import axios, { InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>) => {
    return config;
  },
  (error: any) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default api;
```

```
app/dashboard/page.tsx

const Dashboard = async () => {
  const user = await me();

  return (
    <p>Dashboard</p>
  );
};
```

```
me.ts

import api from "api";

const me = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.get("/auth/me");
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

export default me;
```

I also have a Client Component "Login" that sends a request to /login route and get back a JWT and I save it like this:

`` api.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`; ``

Thank you for anyone helping